# Getting Certain Method Into Main Method in Java

Tags: java, methods

I've written up a code with several different methods. I can't seem to find the correct way to get the last method I have into the main method so it can print out the correct output.

CODE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    int num = in.nextInt();

  } // this is my main method
```

---

```
public void results (int num) {
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
      System.out.print(space(num - i));
      System.out.println(method1(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      System.out.println(method2(num-i));
      System.out.print(space(i));
    }
  } //this is the method that I want inside my main method
```

I thought I could simply put `System.out.println(results(num));` into my main method but that doesn't work. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and help me with this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `main` method is `static`, but your `results` method is not. Either make `results` be `static`, or declare a `new` instance of your class to use inside of `main`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        results(1);
    }
    public static void results (int num) {
    }
}
```

or

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass().results(1);
    }
    public void results (int num) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass what `results` returns to anything such as `System.out.println`, because `results` has a `void` return type.  But `results` already is printing out information, so just call `results`.

```
results(num);
```

Comment: He also should make `results` static.

Comment: @resueman Yes, or `main()` can create a new instance of the class and then call `results` on it.